# Make balloon rise by charging it?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, buoyancy

I am trying to make a rubber balloon filled with air rise by charging it in the vertical electric field that exists in the atmosphere. No success so far.

Here is my back of the envelope calculation:

$$\text{weight of balloon} = 0.001\text{ kg} \times 10\text{ N/kg} = 0.01\text{ N,}$$
$$\text{fine weather E field} = 100\text{ N/C,}$$
$$\text{minimum charge needed on balloon} = 0.01/100 = 0.0001\text{ C} = 100\text{ $\mu$C}$$

$100\text{ $\mu$C}$ does not sound like that much of a charge, so I thought it would be easy. I charge the balloon negative, so the electric force is upwards (E field is downwards).

Am I bound to fail?

Comment: I believe 100 $\mu$C is a rather large charge for a balloon. From what I read, the typical charge on a balloon is on the order of 1 $\mu$C.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that the balloon is conducting, spherical and has a radius of $10\,\rm cm$ and the breakdown potential gradient of air is $3\,\rm MV\,m^{-1}$.

The electric field $E$ at the surface of a balloon of radius $R$ carrying a charge $Q$ is given by $E=\dfrac{Q}{4\pi\epsilon_0R^2}$.
If the electric field at the surface of the balloon is $3\,\rm MV\,m^{-1}$ then the charge on the balloon is approximately $3\,\mu C$.

Given that the balloon will not be exactly spherical and might have dust on it, it is not likely that you will be able to charge the balloon to $3\,\mu C$.